# Можно ли без устройства Direct3D получить объект IDXGIDevice?

Tags: c++, directx

Можно ли без создания устройства `Direct3D` как-то с помощью интерфейсов `DXGI` получить объект `IDXGIDevice`?

Т.е. к примеру без вызова

```
D3D11CreateDevice(..., &someD3D11Device, ...);
someD3D11Deivce->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), &someDXGIDevice);
```

Или его нельзя больше никак получить?

Comment: А зачем это может понадобиться? Это случаем не проблема XY?

Comment: Скорее всего так, просто интересно стало что сделает `Direct2D` 、без `Direct３D`устройства :)